# Collapse toggle not working with Twitter Bootstrap accordion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get my sidebar of 4 links to include the bottom link as a collapsable link. I.e, when the bottom link is active, it should have two additional 'sub-links' beneath it. When the user clicks back to any of the first 3 links, the bottom (4th) link should be collapsed & **not** show the 2 aforementioned sub-links.

Any help on how to get this working is much appreciated.

My code is as follows:

```
<li><a href="#">Current State</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Issues</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Requests</a></li>
<li class="panel-group <%= 'active' if current_page?project_settings_path(project) %>" id="accordion">
  <%= link_to 'Settings', project_settings_path(project) %>

  <div id="demo" class="collapse in">
   <%= link_to 'general', some_path_a(project) %> # this page should be active after the user clicks on the 'Settings' list item link above
   <%= link_to 'invites', some_path_b(project) %>
  </div>

  <script>
   $("#demo").collapse({"toggle": true, 'parent': '.panel-group'});
  </script>

</li>
```

APPLICATION.JS FILE

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Make sure you have jQuery library and bootstrap.js included.

Comment: hi wurde...i've added my application.js file.  it looks like both are included (this is all that is needed, correct?).  Its a rails 4 app so this file is in Assets/Javascripts

Comment: one thing would be to ensue to ref a 'bootstrap.min' instead of 'bootstrap' if in fact you are using the minified version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i ditched bootstrap collapse stuff & the javascript and just did a basic rails'if' statement on the 4th list item (on the 'demo' div i mention above)...looked somethin' like this:

```
<% if current_page?(project_settings_path(project)) || current_page?(project_invites_path(project)) %> 
  <div id="demo" class="collapse in pull-right">
   <ul>
     <li style="margin: 10px 0px;">
       <%= link_to 'General Settings', project_settings_path(project) %>
     </li>

     <li>
      <%= link_to 'Add Collaborators', project_invites_path(project) %>
     </li>

    </ul>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Not sure if its the best way to go about it but it does what's needed.